# UIAlertController memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

I am not using ARC.

Testing for leaks through Instruments gives me the following when presenting a UIAlertController:

[image]

It seems to be complaining about this block of code when I examine the call tree. Not sure how much of this is relevant but anyway...

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
  // bunch of code

  #ifndef NDEBUG
    NSString* err_msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%ld", @"Error number ", (long) error_code];
    // @property (nonatomic, retain) id <DownloadMonitor> m_downloadMonitor;
    [_m_downloadMonitor showDownloadAlert:err_msg withTitle:@"Download error"];
  #endif
```

`m_downloadMonitor` is actually an object of type DashboardController, defined as follows:

```
@interface DashboardController : BaseController <UIAlertViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, DownloadMonitor>
```

`DownloadMonitor` is a custom protocol defined as follows:

```
@protocol DownloadMonitor <NSObject>
-(void) downloadFinishedFor:(UIProgressView*)progress_bar;
-(void) downloadFailedFor:(UIProgressView*)progress_bar;
-(void) showDownloadAlert:(NSString*)message withTitle:(NSString*)title;
@end
```

The method `showDownloadAlert` is defined in `DashboardController` as follows:

```
-(void) showDownloadAlert:(NSString*)message withTitle:(NSString*)title {
  [self showPopupMessage:message withTitle:title andDelegate:self andActionHandlers:@{@"OK":@""}];
}
```

And finally, `showPopupMessage` in `BaseController` (the parent class of `DashboardController`):

```
- (void)showPopupMessage: (NSString*)message withTitle:(NSString*)title andDelegate:(BaseController*)delegate andActionHandlers:(NSDictionary*)handlers {
  UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

  for ( id key in handlers ) {
    NSString* button_name = (NSString*) key;
    NSString* handler_name = (NSString*) [handlers objectForKey:key];
    UIAlertAction* action;

    if ( ! [handler_name isEqualToString:@""] ) {
      SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(handler_name);
      action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:button_name style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)         {
          [delegate performSelector:sel];
          [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        }];
    }
    else {
      action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:button_name style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
      [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        }];
    }

    [alert addAction:action];
  }

  [delegate presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Why is Instruments displaying a leak?
I had a look at these threads:

[iOS 8 Only Memory Leak with UIAlertController or UIActionSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247221/ios-8-only-memory-leak-with-uialertcontroller-or-uiactionsheet)

[UIAlertController memory leak/issues - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906856/uialertcontroller-memory-leak-issues-swift)

They seem to suggest it might be a bug...or it could be a retain cycle that I've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a retain circle:

In `showPopupMessage` method, actions are added to `alert` which retains them. You define blocks that references `alert` (because it uses it). The blocks are retaining `alert`.

So, `alert` retains blocks which retain `'alert: your retain circle!

You should try:

```
__block __typeof__(alert) blockAlert = alert;

action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:button_name style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)         {
    [delegate performSelector:sel];
    [blockAlert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}];
```

The `__block` storage type modifier will reference alert without retaining it (in non-ARC mode): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have stopped it from reporting the same leak, but now it compains about this line: `UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];`

Comment: Also, I'm guessing your code was supposed to replace `alert` in this line `[alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];` ?

Comment: Yes, you're right: I switched `delegate` (which was my first suspect variable) with `alert`. `delegate`must stay as is, but àlert`must be replaced with weak `__block`ref `blockAlert`. And if my answer was correct, don't forget to mark it as the correct/accepted answer.